# Spark NullPointerException on SQLListener.onTaskEnd while finishing task

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I have a Spark application using Scala which perform series of transformation, then writing the result to parquet file.

The transformation part finished without problem, the result output is written to HDFS correctly. The application is running on top of YARN cluster of 30 nodes.

However, the Spark application itself will not complete and exit the YARN. It will remain in resource manager.

After hanging for about an hour (consuming resources and vcores), then either it finishes or throw an error and killed itself.

Here is the error log of the application. Appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this matter.

```
16/08/24 14:51:12 INFO impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: Opening proxy : phhdpdn013x.company.com:8041
16/08/24 14:51:22 INFO cluster.YarnClusterSchedulerBackend: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (phhdpdn013x.company.com:54175) with ID 1
16/08/24 14:51:22 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager phhdpdn013x.company.com:24700 with 2.1 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, phhdpdn013x.company.com, 24700)
16/08/24 14:51:29 INFO cluster.YarnClusterSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after waiting maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime: 30000(ms)
16/08/24 14:51:29 INFO cluster.YarnClusterScheduler: YarnClusterScheduler.postStartHook done
16/08/24 15:11:00 ERROR scheduler.LiveListenerBus: Listener SQLListener threw an exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ui.SQLListener.onTaskEnd(SQLListener.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus$class.onPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.onPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.onPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus$class.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus.postToAll(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:65)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1181)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1.run(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:63)
16/08/24 15:11:46 ERROR scheduler.LiveListenerBus: Listener SQLListener threw an exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

aa

Comment: Mind sharing the code? Is this reproducible?

Comment: can you check the post settings?

Comment: FWIW, running Spark 1.6 across about 65 Yarn hosts, I have a job that gets this error about 20% of the time.
Sometimes, it's prefixed by something like this: 

WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 43.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 205, AF001932.prod.imvu.com): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/1/yarn/local/usercache/jwatte/appcache/application_1492705589019_103715/spark-04076078-cff2-4975-a54a-83db2f658072/fetchFileTemp1780123060245673366.tmp (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open

Answer (score 0):

What is your version of Spark?
Your ERROR looks a lot like this issue

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12339

Comment: I don't think it's the same, because that bug has to do with manually killing jobs.
Then again, this may actually just be a symptom of a code path that gets called from a bunch of different conditions.